google sheets search list of recurring pairs from a column of data
as in the attached file I'd lke to extract from a range of data in column A all pairs listed in column C.
text
I used the regextract function in E2 and it seems works propely but there is a problem.
As you can see in A10 the formula found the pais '6-86' but there is not a really this pair in the cell A10 but '86-86'. It happen also in E16, E17 and many other...
Any idea to solve it?
